# Magento 1.9 CE upgrade product "product-shop" disappears

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, upgrade

I have recently upgraded to magento 1.9 and now for some reason when I add products the description box no longer shows on "new" products, it is still there for the ones that were added before the upgrade.

Looking at the backend I can't really find much of a difference that would cause this.

It appears that the entire "product-shop" div is missing along with all the nested div's below.

Comment: check the product-view phtml file if any condition is ignoring the block to load

Comment: I am doing this but I can't seem to find anything that causes this. The theme is actually built off the RWD theme and I compared the files from a fresh install and do not see any differences.

What throws me off is that all the products already created before the upgrade are still showing but only the newly created ones are missing that entire block "product-shop".

Comment: Did you try cache clearance and re-indexing!

Comment: Did you change themes after the upgrade?

Comment: No I didn't change the themes. I simply upgraded to 1.9.1 everything seems fine but for some reason. I created products and it appears fine and when you go back in to change something like an image or price the whole description disappears. I am clueless

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue and it was related to the images. The images uploaded were rather large over 1mg in size which caused Magento to exhaust the memory therefore not load the rest of the data. In my debugging I saw the exhaust memory error referring to the gdlibrary.

Once I resized the images, everything was back displaying.

I am not sure if this was implemented in 1.9.1 or if one of the publishers recently upload it these large images.